# Problems with drawing graphs in R

Tags: r

I am making a plot of means in R and my data collection started in October and ends in August the following year. the problem is when I draw my graph the default graph that I get has the months in alphabetical order(i.e. april,august,december etc..) instead of the order that I had enter them(i.e. ocboer, november,december etc..). how do I change that?

Comment: Maybe you can share some piece of code as an example so we can try to help you?

Comment: This is not a psychic service. Adding a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to your question dramatically improves the chances of you getting help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your month into a factor variable and then plot the factor on the X axis.

```
factorisedMonth <- factor(oldMonth,levels=month.name)
```

R has a built in month.name that orders the factor properly if it's the standard english names in full